# Multiprocessing with Qt works in windows but not linux

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, python-multiprocessing

I am using Qt for developing GUI applications.

I get an error when I try to create another `QApplication` using `multiprocessing`:

> RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists

I have a main window, which contains a button for spawning a new process so that I can create a new GUI instance. Basically like this:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import multiprocessing
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        btn = QPushButton('run new instance')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.create_daemon)
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

    def create_daemon(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_window)
        p.start()

def new_window():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works in Windows but gives the `RuntimeError` in Linux.
Is this because of difference in multiprocessing mechanism between Windows and Linux? How could I achieve the same thing in Linux?

Comment: What's the error in full?

Comment: @PeterWood Error in Linux:`RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists.` which means Linux did not create the same process as windows does. New process created in Linux can detect the QApplication running in my Main process.

Comment: are you using ipython on linux?

Comment: @Tweek  Nope, but I am curious to know how would that affect

Comment: @NorthCat What about deleteLater, did it work? After app = QApplication(sys.argv) you can use   app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out after some googling of python multiprocessing.

The point is, depends on the platform `multiprocessing` supports different ways to start a new process. There is a very good explanation [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html).
So, what happens is that multiprocessing use `spawn` as the default method in Windows, while use `fork` as the default method in Linux. The Difference:

spawn:

> The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process. The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run the process objects `run()` method. In particular, unnecessary file descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited.

fork:

> The parent process uses `os.fork()` to fork the Python interpreter. The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child process.

Thus, I came to a simple solution:

add `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` bellow `if __name__=="__main__":`.

`set_start_method()` is new in version 3.4. Great to have this update! I am not sure how to set this parameter in previous versions. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helping you:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import multiprocessing
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        btn = QPushButton('run new instance')
        self.windows = []
        btn.clicked.connect(self.create_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

    def create_window(self):
        self.windows.append(ChildWindow())

class ChildWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChildWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I used pyqt4 because i don't wanted to install pyside for that. I think that there are some diffrences in the qt-librarys on cross-plattforms, so that the linux application only allows one instance of the qapplication.

[Here is a mailing list with the same problem](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/pyside/2012-May/000394.html) => "PySide only supports creating a single persistent instance of QApplication. This singleton exists forever and cannot be deleted."